# What does it mean to "pronounce oneself/itself on something""

Tags: meaning

pronounceIt may seem dangerous to express oneself on the future of labour law, since it is widely considered to be in crisis by scholars of the field. There is no doubt that anyone attempting to predict the probable developments by presenting hypotheses regarding these developments runs the risk of making errors. Especially the impossibility to guarantee the relevancy of the chosen parameters and a correct evaluation of the nature of their relations could lead to erroneous predictions. The same applies when one has the ambition **to pronounce oneself on** the future of institutions, structures or procedures laid down in and protected by law.

Comment: I assume it is supposed to mean "express oneself on," as in the beginning of the passage. Something is wrong with all this, though -- I get the feeling it was written with far too much help from a thesaurus. The sentence beginning with "Especially" is especially bad.

Answer (score 1):

The cited usage is relative uncommon today, so you may not find it in many free-access online dictionaries. It's definition #4 in the full (subscription-only) [Oxford English Dictionary...](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152551?rskey=1G3sxA&result=2#eid)

> **pronounce** transitive (**reflexive**).
>    *To utter or avow one's opinions or intentions; to declare oneself.*

That's to say, in OP's context the reference is to people who intend to ***make public pronouncements*** (say what they think, make recommendations) about things like the future of institutions, structures or procedures laid down in and protected by law.

---

I think the easiest way to understand ***pronounce*** here is as an *exact* synonym of ***declare***. But avoid using it yourself, because many people would think your phrasing was at the very least "odd".